# jQuery waiting until first interval

Tags: javascript, jquery, setinterval

I have this little jquery code where I want the content of an array smoothly fadein and out with a certain delay and at the end restart with the first array item again.

It works fine, but unfortunately at the beginning the function waits 5000ms interval before it starts showing the first entry. I would like to start immediately. Does anyone know I can achieve that?

Here is my code:

```
$('.wissenswertes').append('<div class="content"></div>');
var wissenArray = [0, 1, 2, 3];
itemNr = wissenArray.length;

function loopWissen() {
    var i = 0;
    setInterval(function () {
        $('.wissenswertes .content').text(wissenArray[i]).fadeIn(1000).delay(3000).fadeOut(1000);
        i++;
        if (i == itemNr) {
            i = 0;
        }
    }, 5000);
}
$(loopWissen);
```

and a [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/3Sggz/).

btw: if you have any recommendations on general code improvement, you are more than welcome to let me know! Thank you.

Comment: Put it in a function, and use the callback of the last fadeOut to call the function again.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Don't use `setInterval` for this. It's fragile because you're relying on the interval being consistently aligned with the other timed code.

I would just make a call to the function after the `fadeOut(1000)`.

```
$('.wissenswertes').append('<div class="content"></div>');

var wissenArray = [0, 1, 2, 3];

function loopWissen() {
    var i = 0;
    (function loop() {
        $('.wissenswertes .content').text(wissenArray[i])
                                    .fadeIn(1000)
                                    .delay(3000) //  v---next loop after fadeOut
                                    .fadeOut(1000, loop);
        i = ++i % wissenArray.length;
    }());
}

$(loopWissen);
```

I also shortened your `i` incrementing code. Your way was absolutely fine, but this is just a little more concise.

Also removed the `itemNr` because getting the `.length` is very cheap.

Comment: Thank you very much for your code improvements, it works like a charm! I was also a bit concerned about the setInterval in this timing context. Thx!

Answer (score 1):

You can define the function first instead of using an anonymous function, then call it right away:

```
function loopWissen() {
    var i = 0;
    var fn = function() { 
        $('.wissenswertes .content').text(wissenArray[i]).fadeIn(1000).delay(3000).fadeOut(1000);
        i++;
        if(i == itemNr) {
            i = 0;
        }
    };
    fn(); // calls it immediately 
    setInterval(fn, 5000);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Something like this:

```
$('.wissenswertes').append('<div class="content"></div>');
var wissenArray = [0,1,2,3];
var itemNr = wissenArray.length;
var i = 0;

function loopWissen() { 
   $('.wissenswertes .content').text(wissenArray[i]).fadeIn(1000).delay(3000).fadeOut(1000);
   i++;
   if(i == itemNr) {
       i = 0;
   }
}
setInterval(loopWissen, 5000);
loopWissen();
```

Answer (score 0):

Personally I would clean it up a little bit:

```
function loopWissen() {
    var array = [0, 1, 2, 3];
    (function next(i, a, l) { 
        $('.wissenswertes .content')
             .text(a[i])
             .fadeIn(1000).delay(3000).fadeOut(1000, function () {
                next(++i % l, a, l);
        });
    })(0, array, array.length);
}
```